# A stronger version of Fermat's last theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory

Motivated by Fermat's last theorem, one may wonder the following conjecture is true or not.

The equation $x_1^m+\cdots+x_n^m=1$ has nonzero rational solutions iff $n\geq m$.

Here a nonzero rational solution means nonzero $y_1,\cdots,y_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying the above equation.

When $n=2$, the above conjecture is confirmed by Fermat's last theorem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a very well-known false conjecture [due to Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture).

Comment: ... and that it is false is due to Lander & Parkin ($m=5$, $n=4$) and Elkies ($m=4$, $n=3$).

Comment: What about the converse (namely that $x_1^n + \cdots + x_n^n = 1$ has a rational solution for all $n$)? I believe that's an open problem.